# How can Naruto be a jinchuuriki inside the Infinite Tsukuyomi world if his mother is still alive there?

Tags: naruto

Inside the Infinite Tsukuyomi world, Naruto's parents are still alive, but Naruto is still a jinchuuriki. How is that even possible?

Even for an Uzumaki, extraction means death, so why would Minato transfer the Nine Tails to their son?
Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: You said the answer yourself in the question. The *Infinite Tsukuyomi*.  Plus, there was no Naruto Uzumaki in that world, instead they had Menma Uzumaki.

Comment: When Madara released infinite dream on the entire world. Ok, Why Menma was a jinchuuriki if his mother was still alive. If Kurama was extracted from her, wasn't she supposed to die? Yes, In Tsunade's dream it was shown that Minato had to split Nine Tails into Yin and Yang because Kushina was weak post-pragnancy. But since Minato was taking care of the seal while Menma was still coming out, and there was no Tobi in the equation, how Nine Tails came out of Kushina in the first place. @EroSɘnnin

Comment: The movie and wikia says that Black Nine Tails, removed from Kushina, was put into Menma. This would mean the other half of the Nine Tails still is in Kushina. Only if the Beast is completely extracted, the jinchuriki dies.

Comment: Minato could have split Kyubi because he wanted his son to master the power and become a great shinobi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to remember is that the Infinite Tsukuyomi and Limited Tsukuyomi are very advanced illusions trapping people in a dream world where everything is possible and it is designed to make them happy. One of Naruto's dreams is to have his parent's with him so while in this illusion it does not matter that in reality his mother would be killed by the removal of the tailed beast because the illusion would prevent that from happening.

Remember it is just an illusion designed to trap the victim with their own happiness.

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, the correct answer is that worlds within dreams do not need to follow the physical laws of the real world. Dreams also do not need to be logically consistent.

With that being said, a different dream does offer an explanation (Tsunade's), in *episode 437: The Sealed Power*. In truth, the story is actually a book within a dream, which Tsunade is reading. While talking to Naruto, Minato says he sealed half of the Nine-Tails in Naruto and half in Kushina. Supposedly this was done in order to save Kushina's life, but no further details are given with that regard in this episode.